# Is there a way to fix a batch size mismatch between output from final model layer and input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, conv-neural-network, tensorflow.js, batchsize

**What I've done**: I have a complete dataset of 898 labels with a total of ~55,000 images. For purposes of speed, I took 10 of those labels and about ~600 images to test the code below. I've tried changing the batchSize, modifying the data function, but to no avail.

**Problem**: `Error: Batch size mismatch: output dense_Dense1 has 10; expected  500 based on input conv2d_Conv2D1_input.`

**Goal**: Either change the final output of dense_Dense1 to have 500, or change the expected input of conv2d_Conv2D1_input to only 10.

Complete Code:

```
var tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
var tfnode = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
var fs = require(`fs`)

const numberOfClasses = 10;

const imageWidth = 500;
const imageHeight = 800;
const imageChannels = 3;

const batchSize = 3;
const epochsValue = 5;

const createImage = async (fileName) => {
  const imageBuffer = await fs.readFileSync(fileName);
  const image = await tfnode.node.decodeImage(imageBuffer);
  return image;
}

const labelArray = indice => Array.from({length: numberOfClasses}, (_, k) => k === indice ? 1 : 0)

async function* data() {
  for (i = 1; i < numberOfClasses+1; i++) {
    for (x = 10; x < 40; x++) {
      const feature = await createImage(`./images/${i}/${i}-${x}.png`) ;
      const label = tf.tensor1d(labelArray(i))
      yield {xs: feature, ys: label};
    }
  }
}

function onBatchEnd(batch, logs) {
  console.log('Accuracy', logs.acc);
}

const main = async () => {
  const model = tf.sequential();

  model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
    inputShape: [imageWidth, imageHeight, imageChannels],
    filters: 8,
    kernelSize: 5,
    padding: 'same',
    activation: 'relu'
  }));
  model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
    poolSize: 2,
    strides: 2
  }));

  model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
    filters: 16,
    kernelSize: 5,
    padding: 'same',
    activation: 'relu'
  }));
  model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
    poolSize: 3,
    strides: 3
  }));
  
  model.add(tf.layers.flatten());

  model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    units: numberOfClasses,
    activation: 'softmax'
  }));

  model.compile({
    optimizer: 'sgd',
    loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy',
    metrics: ['accuracy']
  });

  model.summary()

  const ds = tf.data.generator(data);

  model.fitDataset(ds, {
    epochs: 5,
    batchSize: 10,
    callbacks: {onBatchEnd}
  }).then(info => {
    console.log('Final accuracy', info.history.acc);
  });

}
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory

> Error: Batch size mismatch: output dense_Dense1 has 10; expected  500 based on input conv2d_Conv2D1_input.

There is a mismatch of shape between what the model expects and what the dataset has.
`dense_Dense1` is the last layer and 10 the number of classes (`model.summary()` is handy to know the layers' name)

500 is the number of batches - at least that's what the model is getting with `fitDataset()`. Here is the confusion. 500 is the first axis size of the `feature`. `feature` is a 3d tensor with the first axis (image width) being 500. If the 3d tensor is used directly for prediction, the model consider that the image width is the number of batches and the features are 2d tensors. Therefore the feature should rather be a 4d tensor.

To go further, the model is not predicting on a single image at a time though. Since there is later a `batch(10)`. After each iteration of the iterator `data*`, the features are stacked and after 10 iterations are used for predictions. It is handy because other operators can be used to reshuffle the batch and so on.

Here is the fix:

```
yield {xs: feature.expandDims(), ys: label.expandDims()};
```

Or even better you can batch the number of samples before fitting it to the model this way

```
const ds = tf.data.generator(data).batch(1);
```

Comment: I tried that, but the error ended up changing to:
`Error: Batch size mismatch: output dense_Dense1 has 10; expected  1 based on input conv2d_Conv2D1_input.`

instead of 500, it is now 1

Comment: I got this after adding `expandDims` to the labels: `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_Conv2D1: expected axis 3 of input shape to have value 3 but got shape 1,500,800,4.`

Comment: I have now added `expandDims` to the labels as well. Or you can just use the second method by batching the dataset samples

Comment: Could you please do the following: `await ds.forEachAsync(e => console.log(e.xs.shape, e.ys.shape));` and report here the different shapes ?

Comment: Your last errors is because of `imageChannels` 3. Either it is set to 4 to match the 4 channels of the image, or you decode the image this way: `tfnode.node.decodeImage(imageBuffer, 3)` meaning that only 3 channels are used for the decoded tensor

Comment: all of the shapes looked like:
```
[ 1, 500, 800, 4 ] [ 1, 10 ]
```
(I didn't copy them all because they were all the same)

Comment: Could you please do what I suggested with `decodeImage` ?

Comment: Epoch 1 / 5
eta=0.0 ------------------------------------------------------------ acc=0.00 loss=16.12 Accuracy 0
Accuracy 0
Accuracy 0
Accuracy 0

I receive the above when imageChannels is changed to 4, same with when I decoded the image using only 3 channels.

Comment: As regarding the accuracy, you need to play around with the layers, the loss function, the optimizer until you reach something that gives a decent accuracy

Comment: It's logging incorrectly. It's normally supposed to log ETA in ms, and move onto the next Epochs, but it's just saying Accuracy 0

Comment: Even after waiting a while?

Comment: Correct. It just keeps saying `Accuracy 0`. After a few seconds, it should look like:
`Epoch 1 / 5
eta=20.0 ==>--------------------------------------------------------- acc=0.2834 loss=16.12 Accuracy 0.28`
(above is an example; I filled the values out myself for how it should look)

Comment: The config object of `fitDataset` ([doc](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.LayersModel.fitDataset)) doesn't seem to have a `batchSize` property. It rather has a `batchesPerEpoch`. I can't tell if that's the root cause of the issue but it is worth being pointed out

Comment: I changed batchSize to batchesPerEpoch, and the script seems to look better (but not function better).


It is still showing an Accuracy of 0: `6509ms 650915us/step - acc=0.00 loss=16.12` (Epoch 5)

But it is also now showing an Accuracy of 1: `6783ms 678327us/step - acc=1.00 loss=1.19e-7` (Epoch 4)


it doesn't show anything in between, like how a normal model training should occur



This is the final accuracy of the model in 5 epochs: `Final accuracy [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 ]`

Comment: You can open a new question dedicated to this behavior and close this one

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the tensorflow javascript [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs), and found this following snippet from the file `https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/550e2c7ced057309533f44f76e692fe28aa7a802/tfjs-layers/src/engine/training_dataset.ts` on line 202, where you will see the following snippet.

```
  for (let yIndex = 0; yIndex < flattenedYs.length; yIndex++) {
  tfc.util.assert(
    flattenedYs[yIndex].shape[0] === batchSize,
    () => `Batch size mismatch: output ` +
        `${model.outputNames[yIndex]} has ${
              flattenedYs[yIndex].shape[0]}; ` +
        `expected  ${batchSize} based on input 
   ${model.inputNames[0]}.`);
  }
```

this is the only place in the entire codebase that generates this error which matches exactly to your error. Though I am not an expert in deep learning, but I can tell the problem is probably at y dimension of your data.

that snippet is coming from a function called `standardizeDataIteratorOutput`, which one of its forloop inside is trying to validate the y dimension of your dataset `flattenedYs[yIndex].shape[0] === batchSize` so in a nutshell, I am guessing, your batchSize is set to 10, which does not match the input Y size. you probably need to rearrange the image data to match that.